# конвертировать элемент целочисленного массива в символ с++

Tags: c++

чтобы последний элемент целочисленного массива был заменен на звездочку,однако,вместо символа я получаю число 42.Заранее благодарю!

```
int arr[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'*'};
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: В чем Ваш вопрос ?

Comment: А так можно в целочисельный масив звезду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что выводите char как int - поэтому и получаете 42.

Если вы добавите проверку в цикле:

```
If (i  ==  8) {
    std::cout << static_cast<char>(arr[i]) << std::endl;
}
```

То ваша проблема исчезнет

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << (char)(arr[i]>0 && arr[i]<10 ? arr[i]+'0' : arr[i]) << endl;
```

Comment: old-style приведение типов....

Comment: @Beeen007, а почему бы и нет?

Comment: Вопрос был задан с меткой С++, код который вы указали это С-style

Comment: @Beeen007, в Си++ он тоже работает.

Comment: При использовании C++ необходимо использовать механизмы C++ в этом основа философии этого языка. Элементы из языка Си необходимо оборачивать в extern "C" {}.

Answer (score 0):

42 это десятичное значение звездочки. Можете взглянуть на таблицу ASCII в столбике DEC(десятиричное) вы увидите что на 42 позиции звездочка. для корректного вывода вам нужно добавить следующее 
char byte_1 = 00101010b;

```
int arr[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'*'}; 
for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
if(arr[i] == byte_1)
cout<<"*";
else
cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

и пусть приверженцы оптимального кода закидают меня камнями.
Есть еще оптимальнее вариант :

```
for(int i = 1 ; i < 9 ; i ++ ) 
cout<<i<<"\n";
cout<<'*';//3 строки кода всего
```